# Making Maven run all tests, even when some fail

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project with several modules. When all tests pass, Maven test runs them all.

When tests fail in the first module, maven will not continue to the next project. I have testFailureIgnore set to true in Surefire settings, but it doesn't help.

How do I make maven run all tests regardless of earlier failures?

Comment: What version of the maven-surefire-plugin?

Comment: testFailureIgnore should work, maybe do a `mvn help:effective-pom` to make sure it's in there in the right place...

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I just found the `-fae` parameter, which causes Maven to run all tests and not stop on failure.

Comment: Sadly, this parameter doesn't work when I pass it to TeamCity.

Comment: In a multi-module project, modules that depend on module that has failed tests will be skipped. Use -fn instead.

Comment: @ripper234 did you found a way to make it work on TeamCity?

Comment: Can you configure this in the pom file?

Comment: This only works for modules that don't have dependencies on other modules within the same build tree, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616700/32453

Answer (score 466):

From the [Maven Embedder documentation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-embedder/cli.html):

> `-fae`,`--fail-at-end`            **Only fail the build afterwards; allow all *non-impacted* builds to continue**
>
> `-fn`,`--fail-never`              **NEVER fail the build, regardless of project result**

So if you are testing *one* module than you are safe using `-fae`.

Otherwise, if you have multiple modules, and **if you want all of them tested (even the ones that depend on the failing tests module), you should run `mvn clean install -fn`.**
`-fae` will continue with the module that has a failing test (will run all other tests), but all modules that depend on it will be skipped.

Comment: additionally you could add -e for the cmd to provide some error information.

Comment: I just tested the option `--fail-never`. Maven will not fail the build even if there are compile errors. If I use this option on Jenkins, the build looks successful even if it has lots of compile errors. I prefer `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` in this case and let Jenkins analyze the surefire reports.

Comment: @wlnirvana I've edited the post now with this link (so feel free to delete your comment...)

Comment: Can you configure this in the pom file?

Comment: @BluE according to [the list of tags](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) it doesn't seem so. Maybe there's a way to specify `-fae` directly in `pom.xml?`

Comment: Testing "one" module I think doesn't fit...With one module test the build will be interrupted when a failure (unit test, compile) occurs with or without either setting.  Unless you're using `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`.  However it does effect modules as described (skips dependent ones unless you use `--fail-never`).  `--fail-never` happens to also return a "success" process exit code FWIW :)

Comment: Sadly neither of these is enough if there are "unresolvable dependencies" or pom syntax error type failures.  Oh well...

Comment: I'm using `-fn`, which *seems* to do what I want, but then the error code after the build is `0`, which isn't what I want. How can I have all the tests run but still get the correct error code?

Answer (score 120):

Either configure [Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) with `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>`.

Or on the command line:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Comment: IIRC this has the effect of the whole build not failing, rather than running all tests and failing in the end.

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me ... The "-fae" option did nothing on test failures

Comment: Yes if you only have unit test failures this will make the whole build "look like" it passed with success.  `--fail-at-end or -fae` should make it continue on and just fail the build at the end, though it also skips dependent modules see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616700/32453

Comment: The great thing about this option is that you can specify it under "Global Execution Options" for Maven in NetBeans IDE, which is great when you can't go around modifying every module's POM (I'm working on a project with 198 modules).

Answer (score 48):

Try to add the following configuration for surefire plugin in your pom.xml of **root project**:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: As explained in other responses, this will execute all tests but also mark the build as success even if there are failures

Answer (score 22):

A quick answer:

```
mvn -fn test
```

Works with nested project builds.

Comment: Is this better than `mvn install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`?