# Build failure on terminal for junit test case

Tags: maven, junit, terminal

I am new to maven and junit so please bear with me :-)

I have created a sample maven project which contains one simple test in src/test/java as folows

```
public class AssertUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void massageTest(){  
        Assert.assertEquals("abc", "abd");
    }
}
```

when i run the test from eclipse, test fails saying that the expected is abc but found abd.
When i run the same using terminal it is saying BUILD FAILURE

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.assertpackage.AssertUnitTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.055 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests: 
  messageTest(com.assertpackage.AssertUnitTest): expected:<ab[c]> but was:<ab[d]>

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.712s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 13 11:36:12 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-   plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) on project AssertProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/support/Documents/Omniture_Selenium_Project/AssertProject  /target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

what is this error and how to resolve it and make BUILD SUCCESS

Answer (score 3):

The standard maven-build will run all tests found in src/test/java and if one of them fails (like your example-test) the build will fail.

So to make the build succeed you have to make all tests pass.

Answer (score 2):

Maven uses the `test` goal of the `surefire` plugin to run all unit tests by default and fails even if **one** test fails. The console output pretty much says so:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-   plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) on project AssertProject: There are test failures.
```

If a goal fails to execute, the outcome is a build failure.

**So, just make your test not fail or [skip tests for now](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) (not recommended).**

Answer (score 1):

The Surefire plugin has a [`testFailureIgnore`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) parameter which, when enabled, does not cause the build to fail when tests fail.

You could add it on the command line:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

([credit to @PascalThivent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176614/1906491))

Or you could bake it right into your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Build, even if tests fail -->
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that this does not stop the test from being run like others have suggested. The tests are run like normal and all reports are still generated. With this setting it is just no longer required that all tests pass for the project to build. Because of this I tend to include this Surefire configuration in all my poms.

Answer (score 1):

During the build process a certain unit test failed.  you can skip the test by  adding the ff parameter `-Dmaven.test.skip`

Answer (score 0):

Maven build lifecycle contains TEST phase which run all jUnit test which belong to project. If test fails build life cycle fails too. This is desirable behavior because you don't want to release application which doesn't pass your tests.

You can fix it by writing test which will pass TEST phase (expected behavior) or you can build application with maven parameter -DskipTests which will skip TEST phase of lifecycle.

*** EDIT ***

Also I recommended you to look at [Docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) about maven build life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Maven proposes three different way to manage failures in reactor builds: `fail-fast`, `fail-at-end` and `fail-never`.

The default way is `fail fast`, which stops the reactor build after the first failing project. To make `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` despite of test failures, you can try the `fail-at-end` policy (using the `--fail-at-end` (or just `-fae`) parameter.

Via: [Mastering The Maven Command Line – Managing failures](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/06/07/mastering-the-maven-command-line-%E2%80%93-managing-failures/)

Comment: Except those options seem to be used in multi-module builds (to allow non-failing modules to build), and the OP has a single project which fails.