# Keep testing maven multi-module even if some tests fails

Tags: unit-testing, maven, multi-module

I'm testing my multi-module project and I would like to continue testing even if some tests fails.

```
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>My Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>project-core</module>
        <module>project-api</module>
    </modules>
```

For example: If some test from CORE fails, is it possible keep with tests of API until the end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making Maven run all tests, even when some fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174696/making-maven-run-all-tests-even-when-some-fail)

Comment: Have you tried to use `mvn clean package --fail-at-end` ?

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise, Maven do some more test but also breaks and not do all of them.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan I'm checking the link and I will try `--fail-never` right now!

Comment: It didn't work for me. Only I found how to skip all tests: `-DskipTests` but it is not completely that I want. But I solved commenting the tests that are failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I could find was: `mvn clean install -DskipTests` and then comment the failing tests.