# Generate XSLT reports for Webdriver scripts using POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, xslt, selenium-webdriver, testng

When my test passes, XSLT Reports are generated but when it fails the XSLT Reports are not generated. 
How can i get the the XSLT Reports even when my tests fail.

I am using Maven to run my tests.

Comment: logic which is used to implement this will helps us to find why it is

Comment: clean compile test site in jenkins to execute the scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Making Maven run all tests, even when some fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174696/making-maven-run-all-tests-even-when-some-fail)

The answer is in the link, in my case i added the following configuration for surefire plugin in my pom.xml

```
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```