# Different test count depending on whether the tests pass successfully

Tags: java, maven, testng, surefire

My project: testng-surefire-maven.
In one of the modules I runt mvn clean install.
When all tests are green, I have a result:
Tests run: 277, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Then I in turn make an intentional mistake in one of 3 tests that I am refactoring right now. And as a result I have 3 totally different outputs:
  Test1>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance:149 » BeanCreation
Tests run: 344, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 100

Test2>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance:149 » BeanCreation
Tests run: 282, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 8
  Test3>AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance:149 » BeanCreation
Tests run: 416, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 205

How is that possible???
All I've done is a one-line change in one of the test classes in turn. I didn't touch testng.xml nor pom.xml.

Additionally, if I make a mistake in all 3 of them simultaneously, only one will pop up. I didn't set a custom skipAfterFailureCount in surefire nor any other testng property. Why doesn't it run though all of them and show me the list of all failing tests at once? All tests are in the same package.

Comment: this is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174696/making-maven-run-all-tests-even-when-some-fail

Comment: Not really. I'm talking about tests in the same module.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know what influences test count, but I can answer a second part of my question.

> Additionally, if I make a mistake in all 3 of them simultaneously, only one will pop up. I didn't set a custom skipAfterFailureCount in surefire nor any other testng property. Why doesn't it run though all of them and show me the list of all failing tests at once? All tests are in the same package.

It happens because testng has a property - `configfailurepolicy`: Whether TestNG should continue to execute the remaining tests in the suite or skip them if an @Before* method fails. **Default behavior is skip.** 
And that's what happened in my case. I had problems on test init stage, not in the test method itself.