# Maven sure fail build when a test timeout is reached even when fail-on-end set to true

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

In a multi-module maven project, I want to print the thread-dump and fail the test when a test timeout is reached. So to achieve this I have used a combination of [TimedoutTestsListener](https://github.com/apache/bookkeeper/blob/master/bookkeeper-common/src/test/java/org/apache/bookkeeper/common/testing/util/TimedOutTestsListener.java) and surefire [listener property](https://github.com/apache/bookkeeper/blob/2f996dcf0159f945f7ec97ce7402e5d293009444/bookkeeper-server/pom.xml#L212).

I am using Jenkins so `fail-on-end` is set to true so that all non-impacted tests continue to run as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616700/785523).

So, is it possible to fail the build immediately only when timeout is reached and in other failure cases fail in the end?

- JUnit - 4.12
- Maven - 3.5
- Surefire - 2.22.2
- Jave - 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in the [maven email group](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201912.mbox/%3CCAKuVzBTGX2Sp-ZQVhYfcT8hT_-CkF6LKBvgR-Ufr6W00LyqCVA%40mail.gmail.com%3E)

> > > to fail the build immediately when timeout is reached
>
> This feature exists for years:
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds
>
> > > to fail the ... when someone presses abort button on the jenkins
>
> This also exists with several alternatives (changed across the
>   versions). See the detailed page
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/shutdown.html
>
> If your Jenkins sends the SIGTERM signal into the Maven process (same
>   as CTRL+C) then the standard input stream in process pipe becomes
>   closed and the EOFException is caugh byt the forked JVM and shutdown
>   is called:
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#shutdown
>   maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#shutdown
>   If you want to kill the JVM, you can reconfigure the default behavior.
>
> If your Jenkins sends SIGTERM to the Maven process then enable the
>   process checker, see more details in the documentaion:
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableProcessChecker
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#enableProcessChecker
>
> Did it help?
>
> Here is the FAQ:
>   http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/faq.html
>
> Feel free to ask any questions if you have a problem with this topic.

If you are using surefire 3.0.0-M4 then thread-dump can be found in `target/surefire-reports` as explained [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201912.mbox/%3CCAKuVzBSi0oAs2eqjWWUSF%3Do5wmA_djwZ0q_2KGDKnDtgUWbd3w%40mail.gmail.com%3E).