# how to get maven to run all tests but still fail build on compile error

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

Suppose I have a multi-module maven project.  I want to run it in such a way that:

- If a test fails, I still want to compile and test the next module.  This sounds like a job for `--fail-never`, but see below.
- If there are test failures, I don't really care if the build succeeds or fails.  Ideally this would be configurable, but whatever.
- If there are compiler errors, then the build should fail.  I think this rules out "fail-never"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use surefire parameter: [`maven.test.failure.ignore`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore)

```
mvn test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore
```

With this options failing test will not fail build a module and finally whole build will have success result.

Comment: fail-at-end won't work for multi-module builds, right?

Comment: seems that ignoring test failures also doesn't help with multi module builds; both facts are documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174696/making-maven-run-all-tests-even-when-some-fail

Comment: ok --fail-at-end skip build of modules which depends on failed module

Comment: Yes, it does, which makes sense in a way.  But the other option seems like it SHOULD work.  I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it seems that it perhaps DOES work.  Maybe I was wrong all along.

Comment: No, seems like I was right... it does not quite run the whole build.  Need to stare at this some more maybe.

Comment: I think I get it; it's compiling all modules but not running all tests, which misled me at first.

Comment: also you can add <testFailureIgnore>false or true</testFailureIgnore> in configuration section of plugin inside pom.xml

Comment: yep, thanks, knew about that; same thing as setting via property, but good to have it mentioned