# how to make a jar in maven?

Tags: maven

I've downloaded source code of jedis(a java client of redis), and I want to make some modification for my need and build it. But when I run maven and select "package" as the goal in eclipse, I did not get the jar file in target directory! And the class file are all generated. What can I do to make them packed?

The pom file modified is pasted in http://pastebin.com/xNrcAXqK. I add a local repository in the pom file, and the remaining part is the same as the original file.

Comment: BTW, there is some test case running during the build, and all test cases failed because I did not start a redis server yet, is that the reason why the jar file is not generated?

Comment: See the answers at [How to build a jar using maven, ignoring test results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365553/how-to-build-a-jar-using-maven-ignoring-test-results)