# How to get maven not to fail a build when it fails a test

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on creating a reporting mechanism for tests and I want it to execute after all of the tests are run, and the resulting junit xml files are written out.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the executing continues after it fails in the test phase. Does anybody know what Maven configuration I could use to get the desired result if possible. Many Thanks.

Comment: I think this has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365553/how-to-build-a-jar-using-maven-ignoring-test-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps?

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```