# Skip test case execution in maven doesn't even compile Test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven

Using Maven build configuration, we can configure it to skip test execution while building the source file. In eclipse we can check the checkbox labeled as 'Skip Test` and from command line we can use

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

The Skip test doesn't even compile the unit test source codes.

Is there any way to configure maven such that it will compile the unit test classes but doesn't execute it?

Comment: I agree with answers below, In case someone wanted to know more detail or how to skip failed tests:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365553/how-to-build-a-jar-using-maven-ignoring-test-results

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It compiles test classes when you specify `-DskipTests` it just skips execution of tests

`maven.test.skip` stops compilation of test classes

---

**Documentation**

- [Skipping Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)

Answer (score 7):

`-Dmaven.test.skip=true` is designed not to even compile the unit tests. If you want to build them but not run them, you could use the `skipTests` flag:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

or in its shorthand version:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

See also maven's documentation on [skipping tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

Add this code in your `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score -1):

When runnig a `mvn install`, you can either:

- Skip tests excution and compilation: `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`
- Skip only tests execution but compile them: `-DskipTests=true`

Note that those properties defaults to `false` when not explicitelly specified.

Comment: Seems like that opposite approach mentioned by @JigarJoshi works for me.

Comment: Was a copy past issue, and now it is fixed :)