# Maven test and then site or other way around?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Currently our pipeline does and this creates a war file and puts in into the server

```
mvn clean test package
```

We are now trying to add surefire reports for those tests, everything works well when all tests pass

```
mvn clean test site package
```

But if some test fails then site does not get called and we have no report.

Although I know that site has tests inside as well so we tried  but even if there was failing tests the site command did not make it to be failing and build succeeded.

```
mvn clean site package
```

What is the best approach to get tests and surefire report.

Answer (score 1):

With [How to build a jar using maven, ignoring test results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3365553/592355)

and https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore:

> `<testFailureIgnore>`(element) `boolean`(type) -((ever) since)
>
> Set this to "`true`" to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is **NOT RECOMMENDED**, but quite convenient on occasion.
>
> Default value is: `false`.
>
> User property is: `maven.test.failure.ignore`.

Using:

```bash
mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean package site
```

Will:

- clean
- package (including tests + test results, unless skipped)
- not fail the build, when tests fail
- and generate the project report (site)